# Removing unnecessary zeros from a BigDecimal instance

Tags: java, format, scale, precision, bigdecimal

I've a simple program that adds two instances of BigDecimal:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("9999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext));
    System.out.println(new BigDecimal("99999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext));

}
```

It works perfectly fine. The output is:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000
1.0000000000000000000000000000000E+32
```

What I can't puzzle out is how to make the result look like:

```
1000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000
1.E+32
```

How can I make the result get an ordinary appearance if the length is shorter than 32 digits, whereas if the result is longer, the outcome should have scientific notation but without unnecessary zeros at the end?

Comment: It is doing this because of the MathContext you have chosen.  Are you sure to want to drop digits of precision in this case?

Comment: I assume you actually mean `1.0E+32`, not as you have it `1.E32`

Comment: not final solution, but maybe you can use something like `system.out.printf(%E\n", z);` it returns 1.000000E+32

Comment: @Anton please check an answer

Answer (score 2):

**This can be done different ways, here is my suggestion to your question:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MathContext mathContext = new MathContext(32, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    BigDecimal[] bigDecimals =
         {
            new BigDecimal("999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext),
            new BigDecimal("9999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext),
            new BigDecimal("99999999999999999999999999999999").add(BigDecimal.ONE, mathContext)
         };

    for (int i = 0; i < bigDecimals.length; i++) {
        if ((bigDecimals[i]).toString().length() < 37) {
            System.out.println(bigDecimals[i]);
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%.1E\n", bigDecimals[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**The output results will look like this:**

```
1000000000000000000000000000000
10000000000000000000000000000000
1.0E+32
```

What is interesting for you is to count the digits of the number by converting it to string for checking process (condition statement):

```
bigDecimals.toString().length()
```

The other thing is to print it in the mentioned/required format:

```
System.out.printf("%.1E\n", bigDecimals);
```

**Examples**
`%E` returns `1.000000E+32` 
`%.1E` returns `1.0E+32`

You can play with it to fulfill your further changes or requirement. I have put your values in array and in `for loop` for demo purpose, that should not scare you.